# Unit Testing a simple in-memory cache

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a simple in-memory cache that looks like (oversimplified) below:

```cs
class Cache {
    private Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

    public String get(String key) {
        if(!m.containsKey(key))
            return null;

        return m.get(key);
    }

    public void set(String key, String value) {
        m.put(key, value);
    }

    public Set<String> getKeys() {
        return m.keySet();
    }
}
```

Now I want to write Unit Tests for this class. I was thinking I can do something along the lines of:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Get_Success() {
    Cache c = new Cache();
    c.set("Apple", 1);
    c.set("Grape", 2);
    c.set("Banana", 3);

    Assert.Equals(1, c.get("Apple"));
    Assert.Equals(2, c.get("Grape"));
    Assert.Equals(3, c.get("Banana"));
}
```

But the problem is, it tests both `Set` and `Get` methods. So if the test breaks, I will not know whether the bug is in `Set` or `Get`.

What is the recommended way to test the `Get` and `Set` methods individually?

One way I thought was, to modify the `Cache` class to accept a `Map<String, Integer>` instance like:

```cs
class Cache {
    private Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

    public Cache(Map<String, Integer> m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Then from the test, I can create an instance of Map and pass it to Cache constructor. Then all the `Set` operations will happen in the map instance that I passed and I can validate whether `Set` worked as expected.

But I am not very sure whether it's the right approach.

Similarly, I want the ability to test `Get` as well without depending on `Set`.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to perform a `set()` and a `get()` as a pair to verify your code. It's very basic logic that you are testing, ie. it's a quick sanity check to ensure you didn't make a silly mistake.

Comment: Unless you're really over-simplifying what you're doing, the object of unit tests is to ensure your code works. If the unit tests breaks, it's not really responsible for explaining exactly why -- it only needs to let you know 'something is broken' so you know to fix it. So I wouldn't stress that you're testing multiple methods. Just do what you need to do to ensure your test will break if the implementation is broken.

Comment: Your code has a *dependency* which is the injected map. This is your chance to separate the "getter tests" from the "setter tests".  The item must be present in the map after a "set" operation and any item in the map must be possible to acquire via your "get" operation.